Custom $reset pinia store method in setup syntax breaks Vitest tests
I've created a custom plugin to replicate $reset method from Options API syntax for setup syntax in my Vue app.
The code of the plugin:
import cloneDeep from 'lodash.clonedeep';
import type { Store } from 'pinia';

export default function resetStore({ store }: { store: Store }) {
    const initialState = cloneDeep(store.$state);
    store.$reset = () => store.$patch(cloneDeep(initialState));
}

It's connected via main.ts file like so:
import resetStore from './plugins/resetStore';

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(createPinia().use(resetStore));

And the function is used like that:
const store = useStore();
store.$reset();

When I run my Vitest unit tests, they fall, where this function is used with the error:
Error: : Store "clients" is built using the setup syntax and does not implement $reset().
Proxy.$reset node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs:1342:27

In this test file (where the error is from), I initialize Pinia like that:
beforeEach(() => {
    setActivePinia(createPinia());
});

It's another store tests, so a component is not mounted.
How can I fix the tests?

If you don't use a plugin you can't expect it to work. Did you try setActivePinia(createPinia().use(resetStore)) ?

Just tried it, doesn't work.

Make sure you use up-to-date pinia as there was a related bug https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues/2052 . If the problem persists, please, provide a way to reproduce as this is something that needs to be debugged

@EstusFlask I use the latest Pinia version. I'll create a reproduction in a few hours and paste the link here in the description.

Turned out the solution is in the docs. Changing my beforeEach function in the test file solved the problem. Using a plugin is not enough, an app instance has to be created.
const app = createApp({});
beforeEach(() => {
    const pinia = createPinia().use(resetStore);
    app.use(pinia);
    setActivePinia(pinia);
});

Doc reference
